# How to remove associate file type from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse recognizes *.glsl files as C++-Header files. This causes the IDE to scan over the content of my *.glsl files and mark a lot of it's content as problems who aren't. Because of this, it's harder to actually get to the real bugs and errors. Sadly, for some stupid reason, someone thought it was a bright idea and lock the control over this away from the user, so i can't delete it in the "File Types"-Settings and i'm pulling my hair how to get eclipse to ignore those files.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is Eclipse, and not a third-party plug-in that is providing these associations?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get Eclipse to ignore them by defining a Resource Filter in Project Properties.

As far as I'm aware, removal of the content type association can only be done by an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The `*.glsl` (and numerous other extensions in your list) are being provided by some tool other than Eclipse CDT. The Eclipse CDT project does not ship editors/associations for OpenGL projects.

This is the default associations in a clean Eclipse Oxygen for C/C++ Developers:

[image]

Therefore, if you have additional tooling installed for glsl files, you may find it easiest to uninstall them, or be in touch with the provider of those plug-ins.